# Reading pdf ebook's contents and split pdf file accordingly

Tags: java, python, pdf

I have some huge technical pdf ebooks and I would like to split them in a way that helps me find and read exactly the parts I want from each book. I am talking about indexed pdf files, with contents (parts and chapters). I have come up with the following splitting scheme, based on the pdf's contents:

**1. Read book's contents.**
 2. Create a root folder for the entire book
 3. Create one subfolder for each part of the book
 4. Split the book in one pdf file per chapter and place the pdfs (chapters) in the corresponding subfolder (part).

How can this be done using a Java or Python pdf library?

Comment: By writing some code. :)  You might also look for libraries that already parse PDFs and ebooks.

Comment: Well that's quite obvious :) My major issue is to find a library that extracts pdf's metadata, precisely the contents of the book it contains!

Comment: I know that. That's why I asked for a **library** to use, not for code. If there is a suitable library, **I** will use it to do the coding **myself**.

Comment: If you read how to ask you'll find that requests for offsite liaise is also not a good question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/) to read and split your PDF files.

Here is how you can export PDF pages:

```
import PyPDF2

def export_pdf_pages(input_pdf_path, page_first, page_last, output_pdf_path):
    with open(input_pdf_path, "rb") as input_stream:
        input_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(input_stream)
        output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        for index in xrange(page_first - 1, page_last):
            try:
                page = input_pdf.getPage(index)
            except IndexError:
                fmt = 'Missing page {page_num} in "{input_pdf_path}"'
                msg = fmt.format(page_num=index + 1, input_pdf_path=input_pdf_path)
                raise IndexError(msg)
            output.addPage(page)
        with open(output_pdf_path, "wb") as output_stream:
            output.write(output_stream)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Laurent. Actually I do know how to use PyPDF2 for such tasks. My question was if there is a library capable of reading the book's metadata (contents) in order to get the Parts and Chapters info I need. As far as I know, you cannot do that with PyPdf2. Correct me if I'm wrong!